# How to bind a GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY to a framebuffer on GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

Edit : see @Rabbid76 answer, question was not truly related to GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, only to framebuffer color attachment activation!

I'm having trouble updating a shader that use to ouput into a single texture to multiple textures.
Here's the simplified code, I'll put all I find relevant, feel free to ask for other parts of the code if they are important.

```cpp
glGenTexture(1, tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, tex);
glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 1, GL_RGBA32F, x, y, 2);

glGenFramebuffers(1, &FBO);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO);
glFramebufferTextureLayer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, tex, 0, 0);
glFramebufferTextureLayer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, tex, 0, 1);
```

frag shader that writes :

```c
#version 330

layout(location = 0) out vec4 col1;
layout(location = 1) out vec4 col2;

int main()
{
    col1 = vec4(1.0);
    col2 = vec4(2.0);
}
```

other shader that uses the result :

```c
#version 330 core

uniform sampler2DArray tex;

in vec2 Coord;

int main()
{
    vec4 val = texture(tex, vec3(Coord, 0));
    val += texture(tex, vec3(Coord, 1));
}
```

The problem is that `col1` is well written in `layout 0` (regardless of texture layer, `glFramebufferTextureLayer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, texDefo, 0, 1);` works as well), but I don't get to write in `layout 1` (`GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1`).
Am I missing something here ?

Extensive tests :

From what I could narrow it down to, it really looks like `layout(location = 1)` doesn't work how I would have expected. With the code provided I get

- val = col1 when `layout(location = 0) out vec4 col1;`
- val = col2 when `layout(location = 0) out vec4 col2;`
  both regarless which texture layer I did bind the `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENTi`, ie both layers seems to work in the `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the buffers to be drawn into with [`glDrawBuffers`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawBuffers.xhtml):

```cpp
GLenum drawBuffers[]{ GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 };
glDrawBuffers(2, drawBuffers);
```

Comment: Thanks! There's still lots I need to learn about openGL so sorry this looks like a rookie mistake... Does this apply only to bound framebuffer or all framebuffers/graphic pipeline ? Edit : from the existence of `void glNamedFramebufferDrawBuffers()` it should only apply to currently bound framebuffer!

Comment: @startresse From the wiki page ([`glDrawBuffers`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawBuffers.xhtml)): *"For glDrawBuffers, the framebuffer object that is bound to the GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER binding will be used"*